# Intel C++ and Microsoft Compiler

Tags: c++, intel, hpc

I am working on a high performance scientific application and found that pushing the computations into Intel compiler gives a lot of speedups by generating fast code, vectorization and better auto parallelization. But my main application is till in Microsoft C++ and uses COM. My questions are

1) Is it possible to build an assembly in Intel C++ compiler and load it into an application built with Microsoft compiler? Will it have incompatibilities?
2) What is the level of support for COM in Intel compilers.

Any advice in this area is appreciated.
Thank you

--Sai

Comment: Here is the reply I received from Intel. Intel compiler has 100% support for Microsoft compiler as long as we don't use /clr in compilation.

Comment: Why don't you post your comment as an answer to your own question? indeed from what I know the `Intel Compiler` is a native x86 compiler extension which simply uses advance techniques on `Intel` CPUs... it is not a new language

Answer (score 1):

Posting Sai Venkat comment as an answer:

*Here is the reply I received from Intel. Intel compiler has 100% support for Microsoft compiler as long as we don't use /clr in compilation*